# How to forward properties of a child component?

Tags: qml, qt-quick

When writing a wrapper around some components, for example :

`MyComponent.qml`

```
ColumnLayout{
    ListView{
        id: listview
    }
}
```

Is it possible to expose all the properties from a child (`listview` here) without typing by hand all the aliases ?

So that I can do something similar to what the following would do if it was allowed :

```
ColumnLayout{
    MyComponent{
        listview.model: ListModel{  // Here
        }
    }
}
```

(Either by forwarding them, either by defining a property that point to listview (I tried, it does not seems to work...), or any other way that permit to bind a property from listview as I would do if I was defining a `ListView`)

Comment: I think an alias is what you want? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases

Comment: In MyComponent.qml, you can do `property alias listview: listview`. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Ow It didn't come to my mind I could alias an id, and use it to refer to its properties, I thought I could only alias properties from an object, interesting, I'll test it immediately

Comment: Indeed it works !!!
Write it as an answer to close the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to alias the id of the object you want to expose. So in MyComponent.qml, you can do this:

```
ColumnLayout{
    property alias listview: listview
    ListView{
        id: listview
    }
}
```

Then you can access it from other objects:

```
ColumnLayout{
    MyComponent{
        listview.model: ListModel{
        }
    }
}
```